# How can I get a string that finishes with one of two characters and replace that last character conditionally by regexp?

Tags: regex, string, replace, adobe-indesign

I'm looking for a regexp formula that finds strings starting with a dash and ending with a dash or a point, it order to manually evaluate cases where dashes must be replaced with em-dashes.

For example, the below text:

> ```
> -hi there.
> -hello-.
> It's nice -said while looking at the window- if you could come.
> ```

Needs to be replaced with

> ```
> —hi there.
> —hello—.
> —good morning —he said.
> ```

But this dashes must remain unchanged:

> ```
> 1992-1994
> MTS-O
> ```

Since I dont think a fully automated solution is posible, i'm looking to speed up the manual review with a single regexp that replaces these two:

> ```
> –(.+?)–
> –(.+?)\.
> ```

With one that match a dash or a point at the end, and let me do a fast substitution that conditionally replace the en dash, when that is matched or keeps the point, if thats matched.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can settle with a simple pattern as suggested. But that might cause problems with some edge-cases. It needs a little more to fulfill all your requirements.

> ..a regexp formula that finds a string **starting with a dash** and
>   **ending with a dash or a point**,

However, if you want to do it in one go you may need a PCRE pattern like this: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wXGXM6/2)

```
(?=^-.*[.-]$)-|\G(?!^).*\K-
```

First, verify the whole string with a lookahead: `(?=^-.*[.-]$)`. If we've a match we are at position 1.

Then, we look for the first dash to replace it, followed by a \G-continue alternative to match subsequent dashes that are not at the starting position `(?!^)`. We skip ahead to the next `-` with `.*` and use `\K` to drop everything before it. Fun, right?

In general, I would suggest using two regexes. First to find/verify the pattern in question, and then do the replacement. But that is probably not an option in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, maybe these simple expressions,

```
(?=-)-
```

or more accurately for ending with `.`:

```
(?=-.*\.$)-
```

with a simple replacement of `—` might work.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ETOqsx/1/)